# Naming convention for similar Golang variables

Tags: go, naming-conventions

I have a couple of cases where I have the same underlying value being represented as multiple types.

Example :

```
userIDString := r.URL.Query("id")
userID, err :=  strconv.Atoi(userIDString)
```

I need to use both the above variables at different places.

Similarly

```
recordSeparator = rune(30)
recordSeparatorString = string(30)
```

Is my approach to naming such variables considered idiomatic go ? If not what would be the ideal naming convention for such cases ?

PS: I don't think this question is primarily opinion based, I'm looking for answers referencing the naming conventions in popular go projects / standard lib.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The likely most authoritative book in the field, [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io/), discusses this topic in section *10.6 Packages and Naming*:

- keep names short but don't make them cryptic (`user` over `userName`)
- package names usually take singular form (unless there's a conflict with predeclared types)
- pick names so that they read in the context of the package, for example, [net.IP](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP)

In addition, there's a nice slide deck [What's in a name](https://talks.golang.org/2014/names.slide) addressing some of the questions and a somewhat informative [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2hwch1/what_is_with_the_fascination_for_short_variable/) that might be useful as well.

Most of the naming conventions in my experience (in addition to the above mentioned) are however project or company specific.

Comment: Do you have any naming recommendations for the scenario in question ?

Comment: Yes @JohnSPerayil two examples from my little corner are the [Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/coding-conventions.md) and  the [Docker](https://github.com/coreos/docker/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-style) contribution style guides.

Comment: What about initial acronyms? Should I choose `dbName` or `DBName` for local variables?